# Умножение на число

Tags: php

Подскажите, как получить 5% от числа 223,66 на php 
Пишу

```
$number = 223,66;
$result = $number * 5 /100;
```

Но в итоге выводится совсем не то, как исправить?
Спасибо, разобрался!

Comment: ? `$number = 223.66; $result = $number * 0.05;`.

Answer (score 4):

Забудьте о запятых в вещественных числах.

```
$number = 223.66;
$result = $number * 5 /100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Числа с плавающей точкой (также известные как "float", "double", или "real") могут быть определены следующими синтаксисами:

```
<?php
$a = 1.234; 
$b = 1.2e3; 
$c = 7E-10;
?>
```

php.net > [источник](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.float.php)

Если не уверен в типе используй функцию [settype()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.settype.php)

```
settype($your_value,"double");
```